# CSV file writing ASP.NET concurrency issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, concurrency

I have a web form in a `.aspx` form which takes a users details and then writes the details to a CSV file in C# located on the server. My question is how can I control multiple writes to the CSV file so the data doesn't get messed up? I must absolutely use a CSV file on the server, a database or other ways to record it is not an option for me.

Looking around I have seen that using a Mutex may be useful. I was wondering what other options I have as I am looking for the most efficient and simplest solution? I apologise in advance as I am new to ASP.NET and C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a mutex/lock is the easiest way; assuming you site is the only writer of the csv file.  Since no code is shown, I'll assume you have CsvWriter class:

```
public class CsvWriter
{
    const string path = "myfile.csv";

    static object synch = new Object();

    public void AppendCsv(string newData)
    {
        lock (synch)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path, newData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is useful. In the code you have an `object synch` is this just a control object for controlling access to the file. It has no other function? Just thought i'd check to make sure I was going along the correct lines.

Comment: Yes, its only used to control access to the file.  Only one thread can own the `synch` (via locking) at a time.